# Is there a generic procedure to find Free energy functional (a.k.a. Large deviation functional) in Non-equilibrium statistical mechanics?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium

In equilibrium statistical mechanics, one often writes free energy functional for a system. But is there a generic procedure to find free energy functional for systems in non-equilibrium statistical mechanics?